# Is there a way to override JUnit to send a response back to another method?

Tags: java, junit, jmeter

Is there any way to create a JUnit test that returns a value to another method? I realize that it should be a *void* return type, but I am hoping to have another method - via Jmeter, automatically run the test before returning a JSON string to JMeter.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testGetPlayer", produces = "application/json",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response getPlayer(final HttpServletRequest req){
    this.response = new Response();
    String newPlayer = req.getParameter("player");
    this.response = pServ.checkPlayer(newPlayer);   

    if(this.testGetPlayer()){
        System.out.println("woohoo");
    }
    //assert that incoming response string will 
    //contain "created player" or somesuch      
    return response;
}


@Test
public void testGetPlayer(){
    for(String m : response.getMessages()){
        if(m.equals("PLS_M001: Player does not exist")){
            assertTrue(m.equals("PLS_M001: Player does not exist"));
        }
        else{
            assertTrue(m.equals("PLS_M002: Player exists"));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to instead have something like this:

```
    @Test
public boolean testGetPlayer(){
            boolean allgood = false;

    for(String m : response.getMessages()){
        if(m.equals("PLS_M001: Player does not exist")){
            assertTrue(m.equals("PLS_M001: Player does not exist"));
                            allgood = true;
        }
        else{
            assertTrue(m.equals("PLS_M002: Player exists"));
                            allgood = true;
        }
    }
            return allgood;
}
```

Sorry if this is an obvious no-no, but I am still learning both Junit and Jmeter and want to see how far I can push them.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about the junit itself returning a value, but you could have a variable in your class such as boolean allGood set to false, and if your assertion passes you could set the value to true in the test method.

Answer (score 0):

Asserts should generally be used to show a failed test, based on expectations. A test should always expect a certain outcome, so ideally your current test would become two:

```
testGetPlayerSucceeds() (asserts that player exists after call)
testGetPlayerFails()    (asserts that player does not exist after call)
```

Usually there is no point continuing a test after an assertion throws, except to assert other conditions, as you are in an unknown state and the test has already failed.

However, there are always reasons to do things differently sometimes, so...

junit test methods are void, so it is not really appropriate to change the signature. The idea is a framework runs them for you, so no return type is necessary. If you don't need to use the junit framework you can remove the annotations and call the tests whatever you want.

I assume you are trying to build a test suite, by calling junit test methods, and need to act on the outcome of a previous test...

The assertion is a type of exception that you can catch in your calling method, set your flag (or act accordingly), then rethrow the assertion.

```
Boolean allGood = false;
try {
    testGetPlayer()
} catch (AssertionError a) {
    if (a.getMessage == "PLS_M002: Player exists") allGood = true;
    throw(a);
}
```